# How to make a <svg> element expand or contract to its parent container?

Tags: css, html, svg, responsive-design

The goal is to have the `<svg>` element expand to the size of its parent container, in this case a `<div>`, no matter how big or small that container may be.

The code:

```
<style>
    svg, #container{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >
         <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

The most common solution to this problem seems to be setting the `viewBox` attribute on the `<svg>` element.

```
viewBox="0 0 widthOfContainer heightOfContainer"
```

However, this does not seem to work in cases where elements within the `<svg>` element have predefined widths and/or heights. For example, the `<rect>` element, in the above code, has its width and height explicitly set.

So the obvious solution is to use % widths and % heights on those elements as well.  But does this even have to be done?  Especially, since `<img src=test.svg >` works fine and expands/contracts without any problems with explicitly set `<rect>` heights and widths.

If elements like `<rect>`, and other elements like it, have to have their widths and heights defined in percentages, is there a way in Inkscape to set it so that all elements with the `<svg>` document use percentage widths, heights, etc.. instead of fixed dimensions?

Comment: Save the svg as a file, than reference it as an image, like <img src="file.svg"/> and that way you can use width:100% or height:100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an svg scale with its parent container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container)

Answer (score 56):

The `viewBox` isn't the height of the container, it's the size of your drawing.  Define your `viewBox` to be 100 units in width, then define your `rect` to be 10 units.  After that, however large you scale the SVG, the `rect` will be 10% the width of the image.

Comment: But the question is: How to scale the SVG?

Comment: @AdrianLang The scaling happens automatically when you set a size on the SVG object, as is already done in the code in the question.  [Here's a fixed version of the example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/8KVtU/).

Comment: You’re right, great, that actually works for me. I guess my problem was the height and width properties in my svg root element.

Comment: [I made some minor tweaks](http://jsfiddle.net/Thyti/8KVtU/452/) to that fiddle to make that resizing be forced horizontally and vertically without preserving the aspect ratio, and made it work in IE, while the fiddle @robertc submitted wasn't. Hope it'll help someone down the road!

Comment: By default your svg will scale as large as possible so that it's completely visible but preserves it's aspect ratio (so a square viewBox won't completely fill a rectangular parent).  If you really want to force it to completely cover the parent container, add [preserveAspectRatio="none"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) to the SVG element.

Comment: This is useful information. The viewbox unit is a relative unit. In my case I had a square viewbox of `0 0 6.82666 6.82666` so i set the width and height attribute to 6.82666, then 100% on the `<svg>` element, through CSS. It seems to work.

Answer (score 31):

Suppose I have an SVG which looks like this:
[image: pic1]

And I want to put it in a div and make it fill the div responsively. My way of doing it is as follows:

First I open the SVG file in an application like inkscape. In File->Document Properties I set the width of the document to 800px and and the height to 600px (you can choose other sizes). Then I fit the SVG into this document.

[image: pic2]

Then I save this file as a new SVG file and get the path data from this file.
Now in HTML the code that does the magic is as follows:

```
<div id="containerId">    
    <svg
    id="svgId" 
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 800 600"
    preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <path d="m0 0v600h800v-600h-75.07031l-431 597.9707-292.445315-223.99609 269.548825-373.97461h-271.0332z" fill="#f00"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Note that width and height of SVG are both set to 100%, since we want it to fill the container vertically and horizontally ,but width and height of the viewBox are the same as the width and height of the document in inkscape which is 800px X 600px. The next thing you need to do is set the preserveAspectRatio to "none". If you need to have more information on this attribute here's a good [link](http://codepen.io/jonitrythall/blog/preserveaspectratio-in-svg). And that's all there is to it.

One more thing is that this code works on almost all the major browsers even the old ones but on some versions of android and ios you need to use some javascrip/jQuery code to keep it consistent. I use the following in document ready and resize functions:

```
$('#svgId').css({
    'width': $('#containerId').width() + 'px',
    'height': $('#containerId').height() + 'px'
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Gazoris, Thanks for this wonderful answer. have question on the same. What if my svg is nested. for e.g., 
<svg>
<svg id="1"></svg>
<svg id="2"></svg>
</svg>
i want to display svg 1 and 2 conditionally and it should take width and height of container.
<div id="container" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>

can you please help me out on this.

Answer (score 9):

What's worked for me recently is to remove all `height=""` and `width=""` attributes from the `<svg>` tag and all child tags. Then you can use scaling using a percentage of the parent container's height or width.

Before:

```
<svg width="3212" height="3212" viewBox="0 0 3212 3212" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   circle cx="1606" cy="1606" r="1387" stroke="black" stroke-width="438"/>
</svg>
```

After:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 3212 3212" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   circle cx="1606" cy="1606" r="1387" stroke="black" stroke-width="438"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you give a working example?  I can't get this to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

@robertc has it right, but you also need to notice that `svg, #container` causes the svg to be scaled exponentially for anything but 100% (once for `#container` and once for `svg`).

In other words, if I applied 50% h/w to both elements, it's actually 50% of 50%, or .5 * .5, which equals .25, or 25% scale.

One selector works fine when used as @robertc suggests.

```
svg {
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
```

Comment: That's because your selector `svg, #container` matches _both_ the `svg` dom element *and* the `#container` dom element. I believe you were instead looking for `svg #container`, but the specification of a parent isn't necessary if you're using an ID anyway.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said, "once for #container and once for svg"?

Comment: Oh pardon, you're right, but your answer is a bit oddly worded leading to the misunderstanding. It sounds as if you're talking about a potential gotcha at first.

Answer (score 2):

For your iphone You could use in your head balise :

```
"width=device-width"
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to scale to window size as follows. A subset of this is scaling to parent. My complicating factor that broke dozens of approaches I tried is scaling multiple SVG areas to the browser window as it changes. This sample uses tailwind.

```
<body>
    <div class="w-full h-screen p-2">
        <svg class="w-full h-2/4" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect class=" fill-red-950 "
                    x="0" y="0"
                    width=100
                    height=100
                    />
        </svg>
        <div class="h-2/4">
            <div class="w-full h-full">
                <svg class="w-full h-full" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <rect class="fill-yellow-400 "
                        x="0" y="0"
                        width=100
                        height=100
                        />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

w-full works for width, but I needed h-screen to get screen height.
Next you use a scheme like h-2/4 to share the vertical space. It is important to keep doing w-full h-full in nested div till you get to the svg which needs the same.

See [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height) for the various options used inside class here if you need to reverse engineer CSS styles instead. A similar approach works horizontally, but there are many more options than vertical. CSS percent or flex or grid etc.