# How can I make an SVG scale with its parent container?

Tags: css, html, svg, scaling

I want to have an inline SVG element's contents scale when size is non-native. Of course I could have it as a separate file and scale it like that.

`index.html`:

```html
<img src="foo.svg" style="width: 100%;" />
```

`foo.svg`:

```html
<svg width="123" height="456"></svg>
```

However, I want to add additional styles to the SVG through CSS, so linking an external one is not an option. How do I make an inline SVG scale?

Comment: try precents in svg widths and heights.

Comment: @ncm How would it be done with JS?

Comment: To set it in JS: `yoursvgelem.setAttribute("width", "100%");` and `yoursvgelem.setAttribute("height", "100%");`  @MawgsaysreinstateMonica

Answer (score 719, accepted):

To specify the coordinates within the SVG image independently of the scaled size of the image, use the `viewBox` attribute on the SVG element to define what the bounding box of the image is in the coordinate system of the image, and use the `width` and `height` attributes to define what the width or height are with respect to the containing page.

For instance, this will render as a 10px by 20px triangle:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 
             points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

Now, if you set only the width and height, that will change the size of the SVG element, but not scale the triangle:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width=100 height=50>
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 
             points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

If you set the view box, that causes it to transform the image such that the given box (in the coordinate system of the image) is scaled up to fit within the given width and height (in the coordinate system of the page). For instance, to scale up the triangle to be 100px by 50px:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width=100 height=50 viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 
             points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

If you want to scale it up to the width of the HTML viewport:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 
             points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

Note that by default the aspect ratio is preserved. So if you specify that the element should have a width of 100%, but a height of 50px, it will actually only scale up to the height of 50px (unless you have a very narrow window):

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 
           points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

If you actually want it to stretch horizontally, disable aspect ratio preservation with `preserveAspectRatio=none`:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 20 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 
             points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This works for me. I first create a viewBox attribute on the SVG element and set the value to "0 0 [original svg width] [original svg height]". Next I change the SVG element's width attribute to "auto" and height attribute to "100%". The container must also have a defined height. This scales the vector to 100% of the container height, allowing the width to float. Finally, set the SVG's CSS max-width to 100% to prevent overshooting the container.

Comment: don't understand this answer. The question is about an IMG tag with a SVG source, not an SVG inline picture.

Comment: @serge, SVG images are just text files containing markup. The solutions here would be applied to the image file as appropriate.

Comment: For the sake of better compatibility, is there a way to do this without the `<polygon>` tag (or other comparable tags such as `<path>`)? I want to do something like this `<svg width="100%" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 20 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" url="/mySvg.svg"></svg>` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 78):

I ended up doing this to get proportional scaling:

*NOTE: This sample is written with React. If you aren't using that, change the camel case stuff back to hyphens (ie: change `backgroundColor` to `background-color` and change the style `Object` back to a `String`).*

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'lightpink',
    resize: 'horizontal',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '1000px',
    height: 'auto',
  }}
>
  <svg
    width="100%"
    viewBox="113 128 972 600"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  >
    <g> ... </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here's what is happening in the above sample code:

**VIEWBOX**

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

min-x, min-y, width and height

ie: viewbox="0 0 1000 1000"

Viewbox is an important attribute because it basically tells the SVG what size to draw and where. If you used CSS to make the SVG 1000x1000 px but your viewbox was 2000x2000, you would see *the top-left quarter* of your SVG.

The first two numbers, min-x and min-y, determine if the SVG should be offset inside the viewbox.

> **My SVG needs to shift up/down or left/right**

Examine this: viewbox="50 50 450 450"

The first two numbers will shift your SVG left 50px and up 50px, and the second two numbers are the viewbox size: 450x450 px. If your SVG is 500x500 but it has some extra padding on it, you can manipulate those numbers to move it around inside the "viewbox".

Your goal at this point is to change one of those numbers and see what happens.

You can also completely omit the viewbox, but then your milage will vary depending on every other setting you have at the time. In my experience, you will encounter issues with preserving aspect ratio because the viewbox helps define the aspect ratio.

**PRESERVE ASPECT RATIO**

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Based on my research, there are lots of different aspect ratio settings, but the default one is called `xMidYMid meet`. I put it on mine to explicitly remind myself. `xMidYMid meet` makes it scale proportionately based on the midpoint X and Y. This means it stays centered in the viewbox.

**WIDTH**

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width

Look at my example code above. Notice how I set only width, no height. I set it to 100% so it fills the container it is in. This is what is probably contributing the most to answering this Stack Overflow question.

You can change it to whatever pixel value you want, but I'd recommend using 100% like I did to blow it up to max size and then control it with CSS via the parent container. I recommend this because you will get "proper" control. You can use media queries and you can control the size without crazy JavaScript.

**SCALING WITH CSS**

Look at my example code above again. Notice how I have these properties:

```
resize: 'horizontal', // you can safely omit this
overflow: 'hidden',   // if you use resize, use this to fix weird scrollbar appearance
width: '1000px',
height: 'auto',
```

This is additional, but it shows you how to allow the user to resize the SVG while maintaining the proper aspect ratio. Because the SVG maintains its own aspect ratio, you only need to make width resizable on the parent container, and it will resize as desired.

We leave height alone and/or set it to auto, and we control the resizing with width. I picked width because it is often more meaningful due to responsive designs.

Here is an image of these settings being used:

[image]

If you read every solution in this question and are still confused or don't quite see what you need, check out this link here. I found it very helpful:

https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

It's a massive article, but it breaks down pretty much every possible way to manipulate an SVG, with or without CSS. I recommend reading it while casually drinking a coffee or your choice of select liquids.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for any SVG -- If you don't have control of the SVG source, then this method fails when the SVG has a fixed width.

Comment: @user48956 You can always manipulate it after the fact with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes - you can always poke at the innards of various file formats with a programming - but you’d hope there’d be a method that works for all kinds of assets (e.g PNGs) and doesn’t require JavaScript programming.

Comment: what if you just have an SGV file, not an svg inline object?

Comment: @serge you add it to your html document as an `<img>` , `<object>` or `<embed>` tag with its `src` as the svg file. This way you lose the ability to modify it by CSS.. however you will remain able to modify its attributes with JavaScript. But if possible, better practice is to use svg inline.

Comment: My friend you rule! Thank you.

Comment: Note that SVG uses actual camelCase attributes (that's not React!). It's like the svg folks just do not talk to anyone else.

Answer (score 30):

You'll want to do a transform as such:

with JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById(yourtarget).setAttribute("transform", "scale(2.0)");
```

With CSS:

```css
#yourtarget {
  transform:scale(2.0);
  -webkit-transform:scale(2.0);
}
```

Wrap your SVG Page in a Group tag as such and target it to manipulate the whole page:

```html
<svg>
  <g id="yourtarget">
    your svg page
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Note**: Scale 1.0 is 100%

Comment: Ok. I don't want JS in this. Is there a way to have it transform to fit parent?

Comment: @bj setAttribute is the same thing as <tag attribute="value">

Comment: What happens if a transform attribute already exists? It is overwritten?!

Answer (score 24):

Messing around & found this CSS seems to contain the SVG in Chrome browser up to the point where the container is larger than the image:

```
div.inserted-svg-logo svg { max-width:100%; }
```

Also seems to be working in FF + IE 11.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  I was only seeing the overflow in iOS though.  Thanks!

Comment: Using both `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%` will make the svg always scale to the container without ever overflowing or losing its aspect ratio.

Comment: @Gavin `max-height: 100%` not works for me, solved by using `vh` instead of `%`

Answer (score 11):

Here's an easy way:

**Type 1:** Most SVGs have a viewbox, like so:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 30" ...>
```

And you can easily control their size in css:

```css
svg {
  height: 20px;
}
```

**Type 2:** If the svg has width and height, but doesn't have a viewport, like so:

```html
<svg width="810" height="540">
```

Then you can just manually add a viewbox that's exactly the same as its width and hegith, like so:

```html
<svg width="810" height="540" viewBox="0 0 810 540">
```

Then you can do the same as type 1.

Comment: Type 2 doesn't work. Adding viewBox doesn't change anything.

Comment: Type 1 worked for me. Basically we just need to add the `viewBox` to the svgs and control the `width` & `height` via CSS.

Answer (score 7):

Another simple way is

```
transform: scale(1.5);
```

Comment: where to add this in svg? this look css

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa in the `transform` attribute. E.g. `<g transform="scale(1.5)">...</g>` or you assign the element a `class` and use css.

Answer (score 5):

changing the SVG file was not a fair solution for me so instead, I used [relative CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).

`vh`, `vw`, `%` are very handy. I used a CSS like `height: 2.4vh;` to set a dynamic size to my SVG images.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to scale SVG without `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

This way SVG will always stretch to fill both `width` and `height`, and to do so, it will resize just `width` or `height`, if necessary, was looking for this for days, so thought to share it here in case someone else is looking for this

You have to remove `width` and `height` from `<svg>` and add `viewBox` attribute and add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg 
version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
viewBox="0 0 5.8208332 15.9"
preserveAspectRatio="none">

<polygon points="480.4,200 0,200 0,0 480.4,0 599.9,100 " fill="#E1E1E1"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the currentScale attribute works in IE ( I tested with IE 11), but not in Chrome.