# SVG scaling adds whitespace/padding instead of resizing the whole element

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to scale an SVG according to user's viewport width

I have this css:

```
.thesvg {

padding: 0;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 50%;
max-width: 360px;

}
```

It scales as it should horizontally, and the aspect is kept

But it adds whitespace/padding to the top/bottom (and maintains original element height) instead of scaling down entirely

But only in some browsers.. or I think so (maybe because of different viewport sizes)

Is this a bug? Or how can I fix this and achieve a perfectly fluid SVG just by managing the width (if possible)?

Comment: Maybe I need to wrap it up in a div

Comment: probably you should have a look at the `viewBox` attribute... http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

Comment: Or this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container