# Responsive layout: Adjust SVG size to fill the remaining space of its parent

Tags: css, svg, uiwebview, cross-browser, android-webview

There are quite a few questions on how to size or scale SVG elements within a page already, but none of them addressed sizing an SVG so it fills exactly the *remaining* available space within its parent - a `<div>` with `id="content"` which already contains some `p`aragraphs (or other elements).

Target platforms include desktop browsers *and* mobile apps (using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) in case that matters).

I am using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) for drawing the SVG contents, so I don't want to use the SVG `viewBox` attribute (which is explained nicely in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19485375/897968)) because that would also scale stroke widths which I'd like to have under direct CSS/JavaScript control.

Here is what I have so far:
http://codepen.io/friendfx/pen/OMxYrL

This works quite well across modern desktop browsers but has the following problems:

1. When reducing the window size such that the SVG element should become smaller than 300px in width or 150px in height (which I nowhere specified but which seems to be some sort of "default SVG size"), the layout starts to fall apart in Chrome and IE and (to a lesser extent Firefox which seems to have only problems with the 150px height).
2. IE doesn't want to wrap the first (long) paragraph as long as the `body`'s `flex-direction` is `row`.
3. On Android the height of the SVG element seems to always equal the WebView's height, irrespective of the vertical space taken up by the two `<p>` elements before the `<svg>`.

While I could potentially ignore issues 1 and 2, the 3rd one is a killer as I don't want any scrolling whatsoever.

After reading the [SVG Specification on intrinsic sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#IntrinsicSizing), I am wondering whether the WebView's behaviour is actually closest to the spec since it makes the SVG (at least vertically) grow to the [SVG viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermViewport)'s size (which I believe to be the size of the WebView/browser window).

Is there a reasonably clean way to solve (at least) issue 3?

By the way, [here is a fork](http://codepen.io/friendfx/pen/PZJrvm) of the above code where I just replaced the `<svg>` element with a `<p>` and which works beautifully across all browsers *and* the Android WebView.

Comment: is this what you're after? http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/OMxKMx

Comment: Yup seems I've override your pen, sorry for that, basically I added this `width:100%;` to the `svg` css, because it was glitchy when I resize the window horizontally or vertically

Comment: @Mi-Creativity: Ah, I see the difference - now I got your code. While the behaviour has improved slightly in Chrome, unfortunately it behaves exactly the same on Android - the SVG's height is bigger than the available space in `#content`, leading to vertical scrolling.

Comment: of course [300 x 150 is specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width), we don't just make stuff up you know!

Comment: @RobertLongson: Interesting read, thanks. I wish it was written as code instead - I think it would be easier to understand. Also I am not quite sure which part of that specification applies to my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through trial and error and following [Mi-Creativity's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846638/responsive-layout-adjust-svg-size-to-fill-the-remaining-space-of-its-parent#comment57434065_34846638) of using `width: 100%`, I styled my SVG element as follows:

```
svg {
  border: 1px solid #0E0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the complete example on Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/friendfx/pen/RrjpeL

The SVG element still doesn't shrink below its mysterious minimum size constraints of 300px * 150px, but I can live with that for now.