# Creating SVG polyline from PHP array

Tags: php, svg

I want to create a line from a php array. Each array element as a point in the line. The x-axis is the key and the y-axis is the value.

Like so:

```
 <?php
 $array=array(10,20,10,50,80,100,40,10);
 $count=count($array);
 $max=max($array);
 foreach($array as $x=>$y){
  $line.="$x,$y ";
 }
 ?>
 <svg height="200px" width="200px" viewBox="0 0 <?=$count-1?> <?=$max?>" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polyline style="stroke:red;stroke-width:4;" points="<?=trim($line)?>">
 </svg>
```

But all I get is this:

[image]

I tried all scaling techniques in:
[How can I make an svg scale with its parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container)
But I still get bad results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Sweet and simple

Your error lies within your defined `stroke-width` and your `viewBox` not being large enough to show all of the polyline.

Depending on your desired result, setting `stroke-width` = 1 would help.