# Make the size of a chart adjust to its outer container

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, scale

I want to embed [this choropleth](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) in my webpage. Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yHznCUN0l35EXE7n4GfJ?p=preview).

Currently, the size of SVG is fixed by `<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>`. If we change it to eg, `<svg width="200" height="200"></svg>`, we will see the map is partially shown, and the real scaling of the map does not change.

However, I want to make this chart always adjust to the size of its outer container. For example, in the case of this plunker, I want the width of the chart to be the same as the one of the right panel.

Does anyone know how to modify the d3 code to achieve this?

**PS:** Another possibility is to leave `<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>` with it, but scale/compress the whole svg to adapt the width of its outer container. I don't know if it is doable...

Comment: To clarify, you have an `<svg>` element **inside** of your `<iframe>`? You appear to be adjusting the dimensions of the `<iframe>` itself, not the SVG.

Comment: yes, <svg> is inside <iframe>.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is **impossible** to style the contents of an `<iframe>` unless you have control over the page loaded in the `<iframe>`, due to **[cross-domain resource restrictions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)**

You would need to style the SVG on the **page that you are including**:

```
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

If you don't have access to that page, then you are limited to styling the `<iframe>` element itself.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, you are right that the problem is inside the SVG. And I realized that its size was fixed by `<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>`. I modified a little bit the OP. `svg { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }` does not seem to work.

Comment: Apparently Internet Explorer doesn't support `max-width` on SVG elements. Can you try adding `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` instead?

Comment: I use Chrome, `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` don't work well.

Comment: I see [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27977344/702977) using `width: 100%` as well, but I could not make it work. Could you provide a working plunker?

Comment: `max-width` should indeed work, but you will need access to the page that the `<iframe>` is pointing to. As in, the CSS `max-width` declaration should be referenced **by** the page inside the `<iframe>`. Keep in mind that with percentage-based widths and heights you'll also need to apply a height or width for each parent element up until a **fixed** width or height parent. If you have a `<div>` container or something in between the `<iframe>` and the `<svg>`, then that element will need `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` as well.

Comment: In this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/09HQffqVaQczO0867KYO?p=preview), I added `svg { max-width: 100%; }`, it did not work at least in Chrome.

Comment: The `<svg>` in your plunker is indeed contained within your `<body>` tag; setting a width on the `<body>` causes the `<svg>` to be contained within. Considering it's running in an `<iframe>`, it's a little hard to make it **adapt** automatically. [**This article**](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) may help you.