# next.js imported svg via babel not scaling

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, svg, next.js

I've been trying to scale my svg icon smaller in my next.js project.

I've imported svg's to my project by adding a file `.babelrc` with

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": ["inline-react-svg"]
}
```

and adding `"babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1"` as a dev dependancy in `package.json`

However, no matter what I changes I add to my SVG file the SVG always renders as a 100x100 icon. I have tried inspecting the code and can't figure it out
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBoSt.png)

```
svg[Attributes Style] {
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
}
```

^ Chrome f12 says this and doesn't say when this is set. (So is this default?)

In my `SVG` file I've tried changing

```
width=
height=
```

and then

```
viewBox=
x=
y=
style="CSS Changes"
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make an svg scale with its parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container)

Answer (score 0):

For SVG being scalable it must have `viewBox` defined.