# Trying to scale a SVG image using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to scale images from an API in JS but for some reason the images are not appearing in my grid items. Ive tried using "width: 2em" to see if it would do anything, but nothing is happening. The error is in the loadPrices function and its directly coming from the line that starts with output += .Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
//For Cryptocurrency Prices (CoinRanking)
const key = 'XXXX';
const url = 'https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?' + key;

//For Tech News (NewsData.IO)
const key2 = 'XXXX'
const url2 = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=' + key2 +'&category=technology,business,science&language=en'

//For Search Page
const politicsData = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=' + key2 +'&category=politics&language=en'
const headlinesData = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=' + key2 +'&category=top&language=en'
const cryptoData = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/crypto?apikey=' + key2 +'&language=en'
const businessData = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=' + key2 +'&category=business,technology&language=en'


//Loads Crypto Data
async function loadPrices() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    const coins = (await response.json()).data.coins;

    const helloElm = document.getElementById("hello");

    // loop through all coins 
    let output = '';
    for (var coin of coins) {
        output += " <center> <div class = grid-container> <div class=grid-item>"  + "<svg src= " + coin["iconUrl"] + "width: 2em ></svg>"  + "</br>" + coin["name"] + " { " + coin["rank"] + " }" + "<br />" + coin["symbol"] +"<br />" + "Current Price:" + "<b> $" + coin["price"] +"</b>" + "<br />" + "Market Cap:" + "<b> $" + coin["marketCap"] + "</b> <br />" + "24hr Volume: " + "<b> $" + coin["24hVolume"] + "</b>" + "<br />" + "Change: " + "<b>" +coin["change"] +  "</b> <br />"  + "<a href=" + coin["coinrankingUrl"] + ">Want to learn more?</a> "  + "</div> </div> </center>" ;
    }
    helloElm.innerHTML = output
} 


//Loads crypto
async function GetNews() {
  const response = await fetch(url2);
  
  const news = (await response.json()).results;

  const helloElm = document.getElementById("goodbye");

  // loop through all news
  let output = '';
  for (var newNews of news) {
      output += "<center> <div class = grid-container> <div class=grid-item <br />" + "<b> <u>"+ "<img src= " + newNews["image_url"] + "width= 156 height=156>" + "<br />" + newNews["title"] + "</u> </b>" + "<br />" + "<br />"  + "Publisher: " + newNews["source_id"] + "<br />" + "<a href=" + newNews["link"] + ">Want to view the article?</a>" + "</div> </div> </center>";
      
   }
  helloElm.innerHTML = output

}







async function SearchQuery(){

    const response1 = await fetch(politicsData);
    const response2 = await fetch(headlinesData);
    const response3 = await fetch(cryptoData);
    const response4 = await fetch(businessData);

    const p  = (await response1.json()).results;
    const h  = (await response2.json()).results;
    const c  = (await response3.json()).results;
    const b  = (await response4.json()).results;

    



}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the "active" element to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto ;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 1000px;
  
  

}

.grid-item {
  width: 50x;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 5px solid rgb(5, 8, 5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;

}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
 
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

.header{
width: 25%;
font-size: 25px;
padding: 12px 16px;
position: center;
background-color: lightgray;
}

#grid-item1 {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 5px solid rgb(5, 8, 5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script src="Home.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homeStyle.css">


<body style="background-color:rgb(2, 2, 2);" >



<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="home.html">Crypto Prices</a>
  <a href="news.html">Tech News </a>
  <a href="search.html">Search</a>
  
 </div>

<div id = "hello">
  <center><button style="cursor: pointer;padding: 2px 4px;border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); background:#30a343;color:white;font-size : 25px; width: 25%; height: 100px;" onclick="loadPrices()">View Currency Rankings!</button></center>   
</div>
  




</body>
</html>
```

!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to resize a svg, you need to set `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`. Then, you can adjust the width and height properties of the svg element:

```html
<svg width=50 height=50  viewBox="0  0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

<svg width=100 height=100  viewBox="0  0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

<svg width=150 height=150  viewBox="0  0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

For further explanation, check out [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) on the mdn docs! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container) SO question could also help!