# C3 Chart resize in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

I currently have a simple donut chart that I created with C3. I have put it inside a directive and all works fine.

My directive is as follows:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').directive('donutChart',function(){       

    function link(scope,element,attr){      


        scope.$watch(function() {

            return scope.data;
         },
            function() {                    
                if(scope.data !== undefined){                       

                    var chart  = c3.generate({
                        bindto: 'donut-chart',
                        data:{
                            columns : scope.data,                           
                            type: 'donut'
                            },
                        donut:{
                            label : {
                                format: function(value,ratio,id){
                                    return value;
                                },

                            }
                        },
                        tooltip:{
                                position: function(data,width,height,element){
                                    return {top:-180,left:300}
                                }
                            },                      
                    }); 
                }       
            }
        )};         

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',         
        scope: {
            data: '='       

        },
        link : link
    };
});
```

In the HTML I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="donut-route" >
        <donut-chart  data='routes'></donut-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to have the donut char re-size within the div it is currently sitting in.

I am aware of the C3 resize where I can pass values through and maybe I could add window sizes to the **$scope.watch** and resize it every time but I am not sure if that would be too heavy. From reading the documentation I think C3 graphs re-size automatically but due to the fact it's in a directive I think it is being restricted.

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put your code in a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QTwER5pCRdSsQYLJsVEI?p=preview) in order to investigate the problem.

Because the generated chart is an **SVG** object the CSS way to resize it  automatically is tricky. However my suggestion is to explore the following post:

https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

or also this question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775448/is-is-possible-to-scale-inline-svg-with-css)

So I think the more effective way (as you stated) is to use size option on generate:

```
   var chart = c3.generate({
        size: {
          height: 200,
          width: 200
        }...
```

and resize method of C3 API to update size:

```
  chart.resize({height:100, width:300})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was thinking that I would have to go down the watch route but it's good to see other options.