# SVG responsive not working in Boostrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m using bootstrap 3 for a full responsive design.

In one of my pages, I need to load a pre-build SVG (from CorelDraw or InkScape).

It runs fine except when I need to go for smaller screen devices (iPad, iPhone). The SVG image does not shrink automatically and gets out of the border boundaries.

I´ve looked at that post but did not succeeded: [post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919076/how-to-make-a-svg-element-expand-or-contract-to-its-parent-container)

One issue: I can´t touch the SVG as it´s loaded by the user itself directly from Corel/InkScape to a server folder, I get the content and load it to the model data (I´m using MVC4).

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id="svgbox" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100%; width: 100%">
    @Html.Raw(Model.SVGData)
</div>
```

I do appreciate any kind of help to solve this.

Comment: Are you able to show a demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
#svgbox svg {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Isn´t it the same of style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100%; width: 100%" ?

Comment: No, inside that div, svg starts with `<svg>` Did you tried that?

Comment: The way you did works fine. But I also tried <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <div id="svgbox" style="border: 1px solid black">
        @Html.Raw(Model.SVGData)
    </div>
</div>
and got no results. Why does the styling in the CSS has not the same behaviour ?

Comment: See you are giving style to `#svgbox`, I'm giving for `svg` inside it like `#svgbox svg`