# Dealing with Vertical Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an x-matrix form that contains textareas that a vertical instead of horizontal as they normally are. I want to make the columns auto adjust when users enter information into the text area, but all the examples I have found so far are just for normal textareas. I don't really understand how the textareas are resized and how being vertical affects those resizing issues. I want the columns to expand with the text area, but the text area should not adjust by itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="colResize.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .x-matrix {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: medium;
            border-style: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .container{
            position: relative;
            font-family: Arial;
            height:480px;
            width:816px;
        }      
        .v-text {
            position: absolute;
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            border: none;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        .h-text{
            width:600px;
        }
        .harvey {
            width:50px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .top-row {
            height: 50px;
        }
        .bottom-row {
            height: 500px;
        }
       td {
            border:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <table id="main" class="x-matrix">
        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
            <td id="h-gi-1-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-1-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-1-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-1-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-1-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="i-1"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 1 here</td>
            <td id="h-it-1-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-2-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-3-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-4-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-5-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
            <td id="h-gi-2-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-2-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-2-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-2-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-2-5"  class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="i-2"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 2  here</td>
            <td id="h-it-1-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-2-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-3-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-4-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-5-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>

        </tr>        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
            <td id="h-gi-3-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-3-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-3-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-3-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-3-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="i-3"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 3 here</td>
            <td id="h-it-1-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-2-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-3-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-4-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-5-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>

        </tr>        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
            <td id="h-gi-4-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-4-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-4-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-4-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-4-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="i-4"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 4 here</td>
            <td id="h-it-1-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-2-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-3-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-4-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-5-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>

        </tr>        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
            <td id="h-gi-5-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-5-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-5-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-5-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-gi-5-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="i-5"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative5 here</td>
            <td id="h-it-1-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-2-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-3-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-4-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            <td id="h-it-5-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr class=bottom-row>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919076/how-to-make-a-svg-element-expand-or-contract-to-its-parent-container-->
                <div id="containerId">    
                        <svg
                        id="svgId" 
                        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        version="1.1"
                        x="0"
                        y="0"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        viewBox="0 0 500 600"
                        preserveAspectRatio="none">
                        <style>
                            .caption { font: bold 20px sans-serif; fill: #bd1c1c; }
                        </style>
                        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="600" stroke="black" />
                        <line x1="0" y1="600" x2="500" y2="0" stroke="black" />
                        <text id="top_caption" class="caption" x="150" y="20" transform="rotate (0  0,0)">Strategic Initiatives</text>
                        <text id="left_caption" class="caption" x="200" y="20" transform="rotate (270 300,300)">Strategic Goals</text>
                        <text id="right_caption" class="caption" x="150" y="20" transform="rotate (270 500,30)">Strategic Targets</text>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <textarea id="g-1" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left:-220px">Goal 1. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="g-2" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left:-176px">Goal 2. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="g-3" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left:-133px">Goal 3. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="g-4" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: -96px">Goal 4. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="g-5" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: -54px">Goal 5. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="t-1" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 392px">Target 1. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="t-2" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 435px">Target 2. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="t-3" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 475px">Target 3. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="t-4" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 517px">Target 4. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
    <textarea id="t-5" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 558px">Target 5. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using _flexbox_ with [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)?

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks for the info

Comment: Maybe writing-mode is a hint and then setting textarea inside the td they are supposed to make grow will make things easier : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eXeVmr is that looking closer to what you try to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure is wrong. See the example below. Hope to help.

```js
function autochange(elem){
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.style.cssText = 'height:auto;';
    elem.style.cssText = 'height:' + elem.scrollHeight + 'px;';
  },0);
}
```

```css
.container{
    margin: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}      
.v-text {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(270deg);transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    border: none;
    font-family: Arial;
}
textarea{  
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container v-text">
    <textarea onkeydown='autochange(this);' id="t-1" rows = "2" cols="65">Vertical textarea by automatic resizing.</textarea>
    <textarea onkeydown='autochange(this);' id="t-5" rows = "2" cols="65">Vertical textarea by automatic resizing.</textarea>
    <textarea onkeydown='autochange(this);' id="t-5" rows = "2" cols="65">Vertical textarea by automatic resizing.</textarea>
       <textarea onkeydown='autochange(this);' id="t-5" rows = "2" cols="65">Vertical textarea by automatic resizing.</textarea>
        <textarea onkeydown='autochange(this);' id="t-5" rows = "2" cols="65">Vertical textarea by automatic resizing.</textarea>
</div>
```