# How to make a textarea stay in the right spot when adding or removing rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

[image]I have a form for a x-matrix and I have to be able to add and delete columns or rows. I have text areas on specific spots on the form that correspond with the rows above them. When I add or delete rows the text areas stay in the same position on the page and I need them to move according to rows or columns being deleted. I tried to put the text areas in the table, but it just centers the text area on the form. I need **Goal 1** to line up on the outer-most column on the **left** and I need **Target one** to line up on the inner-most column on the **right** side of the form.

```js
     function addRow(tableID) {
     
      var text = "Enter Initiative ";
      
      
     
      var table = document.getElementById("main");
      
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount - 1);
      
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      cell1.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      cell2.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      cell3.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      cell4.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      cell5.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
      cell6.innerHTML = text + " " + rowCount;
      
      var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
      cell7.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
      cell8.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
      cell9.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
      cell10.innerHTML = "HB";
      
      var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
      cell11.innerHTML = "HB";
     }
     
     function deleteRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById("main");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    
        table.deleteRow(rowCount -2);
    }
```

```css
            .x-matrix {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: medium;
                border-style: none;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .container{
                position: relative;
                font-family: Arial;
                height:480px;
                width:816px;
       margin: auto;
            }      
            .v-text {
                position: absolute;
                transform: rotate(270deg);
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                border: none;
                font-family: Arial;
       resize:vertical;
       flex-direction: row;
            }
            .h-text{
                width:600px;
            }
            .harvey {
                width:50px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .top-row {
                height: 50px;
            }
            .bottom-row {
                height: 500px;
            }
           td {
                border:solid;
                border-width:1px;
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
      tr {
       width:50px;
                text-align: center;
       
      }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <input type = "button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('main')"/>
    <input type = "button" value="Delete One Row" onclick="deleteRow('main')"/>
     
        <div class="container">
        <table id="main" class="x-matrix">
            <tr class="top-row" id="top">
                <td id="h-gi-1-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-1-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-1-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-1-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-1-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="i-1"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 1 here</td>
                <td id="h-it-1-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-2-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-3-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-4-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-5-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="top-row" id="top">
                <td id="h-gi-2-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-2-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-2-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-2-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-2-5"  class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="i-2"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 2  here</td>
                <td id="h-it-1-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-2-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-3-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-4-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-5-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
    
            </tr>        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
                <td id="h-gi-3-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-3-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-3-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-3-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-3-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="i-3"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 3 here</td>
                <td id="h-it-1-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-2-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-3-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-4-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-5-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
    
            </tr>        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
                <td id="h-gi-4-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-4-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-4-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-4-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-4-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="i-4"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative 4 here</td>
                <td id="h-it-1-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-2-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-3-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-4-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-5-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
    
            </tr>        <tr class="top-row" id="top">
                <td id="h-gi-5-1" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-5-2" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-5-3" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-5-4" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-gi-5-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="i-5"      class="h-text">Enter Intiative5 here</td>
                <td id="h-it-1-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-2-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-3-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-4-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
                <td id="h-it-5-5" class="harvey"><img src="../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg" /></td>
    
            </tr>
            
            <tr class=bottom-row>
    
                <td></td>
                <td><textarea id="g-2" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="text-align:center">Goal 2. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><textarea id="g-1" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text">Goal 1. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919076/how-to-make-a-svg-element-expand-or-contract-to-its-parent-container-->
                    <div id="containerId">    
                            <svg
                            id="svgId" 
                            xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            version="1.1"
                            x="0"
                            y="0"
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                            viewBox="0 0 500 600"
                            preserveAspectRatio="none">
                            <style>
                                .caption { font: bold 20px sans-serif; fill: #bd1c1c; }
                            </style>
                            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="600" stroke="black" />
                            <line x1="0" y1="600" x2="500" y2="0" stroke="black" />
                            <text id="top_caption" class="caption" x="150" y="20" transform="rotate (0  0,0)">Strategic Initiatives</text>
                            <text id="left_caption" class="caption" x="200" y="20" transform="rotate (270 300,300)">Strategic Goals</text>
                            <text id="right_caption" class="caption" x="150" y="20" transform="rotate (270 500,30)">Strategic Targets</text>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        
        <textarea id="g-3" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left:-133px">Goal 3. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="g-4" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: -96px">Goal 4. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="g-5" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: -54px">Goal 5. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="t-1" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 392px">Target 1. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="t-2" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 435px">Target 2. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="t-3" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 475px">Target 3. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="t-4" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 517px">Target 4. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        <textarea id="t-5" rows = "2" cols="65" class="v-text"  style="bottom :-30px; left: 558px">Target 5. Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimball in the wabe, and the mome raths outgrabe.</textarea>
        
        
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely positioning the textareas?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes

Comment: Use relative positioning instead.